# Uninitialized byte array is Scala

Tags: arrays, performance, scala, initialization

There is such a code in [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java)

```
buf = new byte[size];
```

Can you do the same in Scala, without wasting time with unnecessary initialization every element?

Comment: It does initialize every element (to 0) in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala equivalent:

```
val buf = new Array[Byte](size)
```

Comment: It's too easy to confuse this one with `val buff = Array(size)` which will give entirely different result (array with a single integer in it)

Comment: @om-nom-nom It is even easier to confuse with `Array[Byte](size)`. `new Array[Byte](size)` and `Array[Byte](size)` look like exact copies of each other but give absolutely different results.

Comment: If we say `Array[Byte](4000)`, does this mean we have a byte array up to 4000 bytes? From what I remember, a byte is 8 bits long and a byte can be used to represent any character or integer right?

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing it would be with the `.ofDim` method of the companion's object:

```
scala> val buf = Array.ofDim[Byte](10)
buf: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

(the [code behind it](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L218) is the same as @Nyavro's answer, so his solution actually skips one  call).

---

One instance where `.ofDim` could be useful is when creating multi-dimensional arrays (up to five dimensions):

```
scala> val buf = Array.ofDim[Byte](5, 5)
buf: Array[Array[Byte]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

---

The [Array companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$) contains other useful methods to create arrays (for instance the `.fill` and `.tabulate` methods)